# Best way to run script from several forms on my site

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm very new to this and trying to figure out the best way to accomplish. I am using Shopify and have been trying to implement a script that runs upon account creation that redirects to my shop page and also subscribes them to my mail list. I have this code in my account.liquid file.

```
//if(document.referrer == "https://example.com/challenge" || document.referrer == "https://example.com"){

var url = "http://example.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=48c8cbb03628105f109c9ea64&id=111111111"
var email = $('.email.note').html();
var path = "https://example.com/collections/all";


setTimeout( function() {  window.location.href= path; }, 3000);


$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {EMAIL : email},
      dataType: 'jsonp',  
});


//}
```

I currently have a form on my home page and also a popup that uses the same form in my shop page that both create a customer account. Before I commented out the document.referrer it worked properly only when there was a challenge, but without the challenge it did not work. Now commented out it will run properly, but will also run the script anytime a customer goes to their account page. I obviously only want it to run once upon account creation.

I have a feeling there is a better way to accomplish this and have spent hours searching, but haven't found anything.